# OOP in Javascript: questions about classes, attribs, and builder functions

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am trying to use OOP in Javascript. I have two questions respect to this:
I have found a strange behavior in this code:

```
function Apple(pParam){
    this.var1 = "default value";
    this.init = function(){var1 = pParam;};
    this.getValue = function(){return var1;};
}

obj = new Apple("new value");
obj.init();
alert(obj.getValue()); //returns 'new value'
alert(obj.var1); //returns 'default value'
```

I expected same result in both alerts but these are different... it likes 'var1' has different interpretation if this is called as variable or from getter function.

Other question: how I can implement "init" function as builder, implicitly?? (as C++ or Java)

Thanks!!

Comment: `var1 !== this.var1`. You just created an implicit global variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again with

```
function Apple(pParam){
    this.var1 = "default value";
    this.init = function(){this.var1 = pParam;};
    this.getValue = function(){return this.var1;};
}
```

Note: the `this.` in init and getValue.

If you just say `{var1 = pParam;}` with out the this, javascript tries to find a local variable with the name var1, it will not find one. Javascript will then try and find it in the global scope, it still does not find it. It will then create a variable in the global scope (window is the global scope if you are in a web browser).
Similar in your getValue function javascript will find the var1 in the global scope unless you tell it to look in this.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/486qh6qw/ for an example of this.

In answer to the second part of the question you have two options. Either just do it in the function Apple (which I think your thinking of as a class declaration) as such:

```
function Apple(pParam){
    this.var1 = "default value";
    this.getValue = function(){return this.var1;};

    this.var1 = pParam;
    // We can put arbitrary code here for example:
    if(this.var1 === 'blue') {
       this.isBlue = true;
    } else {
       this.isBlue = false;
    }
};
```

The other option is to call the init function from the Apple function

```
function Apple(pParam){
    this.var1 = "default value";

    // as the init function should not be called outside this function we
    // can hide it by making it a local variable.
    var init = function(apple){apple.var1 = pParam;};

    this.getValue = function(){return this.var1;};

    init(this);
};
```

Comment: This code works. Following your clue about 'this' word, I have added to class 'this.init()' to use as implicit builder. Thanks!

Comment: Good examples. Now it's like more easy! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want the property `var1` from your `Apple` instance. Here, in your `init` function, `this.var1` will do nicely, since functions called as methods on an object will be supplied with a `this` variable set to the owning object (i.e., a call to `obj.init()` calls `init` with `this` set to `obj`).

Instead, in your code, you're assigning `pParam` to a *variable* named `var1`, not the property named `var1`. Because you haven't made a declaration like `var var1;` anywhere (and because you are not in strict mode), `var1` it is treated an implicit global variable.